# Is using travel agents in Canada for itinerary mandatory?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens, itineraries

Is it mandatory I use an Agent in Canada to schedule an itinerary?

Comment: What do you mean by "Agent?" Why do you think an "agent" might be required? Thousands of people travel to Canada every year after planning their own trips.

Comment: By agent , I mean travel agent. So You mean I can build my own Itinerary without an agent? I can just schedule trips? I am quite novice to few things like this

Comment: You can build any itinerary you want, but we aware of any visa restrictions at your destination **AND** in transit, as well as all the documentation required to get those visas. Note that in some situations, you are required to submit already booked travel and accommodation with your visa application, but a visa is never guaranteed, so in those cases you should make sure you can cancel and get a full refund. A **good** travel agent should be able to assist you with all that, but it's definitely not a requirement in this context (it can be when visiting some specific countries, but not Canada).

Comment: Before you all get too sarcastic, I think from the OP's context they mean making travel bookings when a visitor visa (from Nigeria) is required. Obviously they're free to make their own bookings but those might cause them to get rejected for the visitor visa. Probably they want to revise the title to *"...recommended, for visitors who would require a visitor visa?"*

Answer (score 16):

**No, absolutely and definitely not.**

Canadian immigration is very clear that nothing about applying for a visa needs to be done by an agent. Everything can be done by the person making the application. In fact Canadian Immigration actively warns about false information being put about by unscrupulous agents claiming that an agent was necessary for some things.

With regard to the itinerary, all that is needed is a description of roughly what you intend to be doing and where in Canada you are going. It does not have to include booked tickets or hotels. It certainly does not have to be created by a travel agent. Immigration understand that most people wait until they have a visa before booking things.